# What is the largest screen boundry of the dynamic elements of a (Flash) SWF

Tags: flash

I am dealing with SWF's that someone else made, mostly pure animation and graphics from the Flash Authoring tool (no programmatic activity, no data or net access).

How do I tell how much space on my page to give them? How can I tell the bounds of their dynamically moving elements?

Answer (score 0):

I remember a limit of 2880x2880, but I think that was in authoring.

What you can do is

- get the dimensions of the loaded content
  in the INIT handler of your loader
- use [SWFReader](http://www.senocular.com/index.php?id=2.43) or a similar class
  to get the swf width and height, in
  case the designer didn't add a mask
  in his main timeline to keep elements
  from displaying outside the stage.

Comment: 2880x2880 is [also] the upper bound on bitmapdata dimensions in flash 9.  (maybe it is also the answer to this question too.)